# ¿Cómo podría cambiar el color de varios formularos y controles windowsforms?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, color

Quiero poner que al presionar un botón se active un modo oscuro para mi proyecto. Que se cambie el color de los controles y forms del proyecto.

Answer (score -1):

Deberás utilizar lo siguiente:

```
  private void buttonCambioColor_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e){

    form.BackColor = color.black;
    control.BackColor= Color.Black;

     }
```

Answer (score -1):

Debes activar esa opcion en los botones dandole click:

[image: Debes activar esa opcion en los botones dandole click]

indicas el color:
[image: indicas el color]

```
button2.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(69)))), ((int)(((byte)(62)))), ((int)(((byte)(58)))));
```

Comment: Es mejor si copias el código en lugar de poner una imagen del mismo.